# Custom component in Android class library project

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

We want to create an `Android Class Library` to reuse some code, mainly custom views.

I have successfully created and referenced the views in Xamarin.Android projects.

The only issue I've got is I cannot use the `declare-styleable`. The view is looking fine, but can't use `custom attributes` in the `XML layout`.

```
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="MyCustomView">
    <attr name="srcLittle" format="reference" />
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

And this is how I use it:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/res-auto"
    [...] >

    [...]

        <Core.MyCustomView
            android:id="@+id/item_proposal_validation_trips_icon"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            app:srcLittle="@drawable/ic_plane" />  <-- ERROR
    [...]   

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Error in XML:

> The "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/res-auto:srcLittle" attribute is not declared

Error compiling:

> 1: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'srcLittle' in package 'res-auto'

Thanks.

Comment: The `app` namespace is wrong. It should be `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto`. You've got an extra `res/` in there.

Comment: @MikeM. I can't believe it... Post it as an answer and I will pick it (before Visual Studio changes it's mind again)

Comment: Oh, you got it? Just needed to rebuild, probably, yeah?

Comment: @MikeM. Yes, I didn't get it at first because some other error was not letting me compile. Feel free to post the asnwer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace you've defined for the `app` prefix in your layout is incorrect.

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/res-auto"
```

The correct namespace for your app-defined attributes is `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto`. You've got an extra `res/` in there. It should be:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```